# How to set the initial date of PrimeFaces p:schedule?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

The `<p:schedule>` always shows today's date as initial date. I would like to change the initial date to an arbitrary date. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i was able to display the date i what i want to display from Calendar to the Schedule

I have used

#### Calendar Schedule

```
        <p:calendar   value="#{Bean.value}" />
            <br/>
      <p><p:commandButton oncomplete="dialog.show()" value="Submit"  update="display"/></p>

        <p:schedule id="display" initialDate="#{Bean.value}" view="agendaDay" widgetWar="dialog" />
```

and for bean i used Getters & Setters and finally the Result is

http://i46.tinypic.com/2j26mvt.png